Splitting an Equation Across Two Pages
I would like to split the code below so that part of it appears on one page and the remaining part on the next page, while assigning a single equation number to the entire group of equations. Please refer to the attached picture. When I use \begin{align}, each equation is numbered separately, which is not what I want. Could someone please advise on how to resolve this issue?
\begin{equation}
\label{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{f}(\chi)&=\mathbb{E}_{a}\widehat{\mathds{1}_{a\cdot A}}(\chi)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{a}\mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{a\cdot A}(x)\overline{\chi(x)}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{a}\mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(a^{-1}x)\overline{\chi(x)}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{a}\mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(x)\overline{\chi(ax)}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{a}\mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(x)\overline{\psi_a(x)}\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{a}\widehat{\mathds{1}_A}(\psi_a), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}



just split it into two aligned one in equation and one in equation* (depending where you want the equation number)

@DavidCarlisle, I want the equals sign to be at the same level on each page. I don't think your suggestion can achieve this.

use \phantom{\widehat{f}(\chi)} as the left hand side on the second page

@DavidCarlisle, I am a bit confused by your suggestion. Could you please provide it as an answer?

@DavidCarlisle, I think I get it, but I have a question: What does \phantom do as a command? Thanks!

it makes a space as big as the content, it's a "ghost" term

The following implements David's suggestion to use \phantom as a left-hand side filler/ghost on the subsequent page; you can adjust the split where needed, as well as which side/page should have the number (by swapping the appropriate elements around):

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,dsfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5][1-3]
\begin{align*}
  \widehat{f}(\chi) 
    &= \mathbb{E}_a \widehat{\mathds{1}_{a\cdot A}}(\chi) \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{a\cdot A}(x) \overline{\chi(x)} \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(a^{-1}x) \overline{\chi(x)}
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \phantom{\widehat{f}(\chi)} % Phantom LHS to match above setup (for symmetry)
      &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(x) \overline{\chi(ax)} \\
      &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(x) \overline{\psi_a(x)} \\
      &= \mathbb{E}_a \widehat{\mathds{1}_A}(\psi_a), 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}

Things to note:

It might not be necessary to use \phantom as the connection in spacing of the left-/right-hand side of the equation is lost around a page break, unless one side is arbitrarily longer/wider than the other. This change is even less noticeable in a twosided document, where the text block boundary changes from left/verso to right/recto pages. Moreover, for proper alignment across the page boundary in a broken setup as above, you'll need to supply an appropriate (longest/widest) \phantom for the right-hand side as well (within the second aligned) like this:
\begin{align*}
  \widehat{f}(\chi) 
    &= \mathbb{E}_a \widehat{\mathds{1}_{a\cdot A}}(\chi) \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{a\cdot A}(x) \overline{\chi(x)} \\
    &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(a^{-1}x) \overline{\chi(x)}
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \phantom{\widehat{f}(\chi)} % Phantom LHS from above
      &= \makebox[0pt][l]{$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(x) \overline{\chi(ax)}$}
         \hphantom{\mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(a^{-1}x) \overline{\chi(x)}} \\ % Phantom (widest) RHS from above
      &= \mathbb{E}_a \mathbb{E}_x \mathds{1}_{A}(x) \overline{\psi_a(x)} \\
      &= \mathbb{E}_a \widehat{\mathds{1}_A}(\psi_a), 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}


To get an unnumbered align, use align*. Alternatively, if you just want a particular line in align to be numbered, and not all, you can use \nonumber or \notag within the particular line that you don't want numbered.

Think about the end user of your writings. Will they be comfortable with the split equation and number when referenced elsewhere? You could also present it in a different way horizontally rather than vertically, for example.
Similarly, break the equation up with phrasing statements explaining some of the insertions/suppositions, rather than just listing them all in the equation.


